# my battery is not detected what should i do

Tags: battery

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 (but had the same problem on 15.10) on lenovo yoga 300 and it didn't display battery status. I checked it in terminal using command

```
$ acpitool -B
Battery status : <not available>
```

and also:

```
$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
native-path: (null)
power supply: no
updated: Thursday 01 January 1970 05:30:00 AM IST (1477251370 seconds ago)
has history: no
has statistics: no
unknown
warning-level: unknown
icon-name: '(null)'
```

Comment: i also used 16.04 but same problem persists

Comment: can i get a solution please